# Unit-testing a custom CLion plugin

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clion, intellij-plugin

I am currently developing a plugin for CLion, and wanted to know if there is any way of using Intellijs testing framework for plugins.

I am talking about classes like `LightPlatformCodeInsightFixtureTestCase` and `LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase` which I don't seem to find, if I use CLion as Intellij Platform Plugin SDK. Using CLion as plugin SDK is crucial, as I'm working with classes like `CMakeProfile` and `CidrLauncher`.

Some additional information: I am using *CLion CL-181.5281.33 (java version "1.1.0_60")*. The package `com.intellij.testFramework` does not seem to include the `fixtures` package.

If I switch to *IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition IC-181.5281.24 (java version "1.8.0_60")* as my project SDK I can import the classes and my project builds.

Am I missing something or can I simply not use the intellij test framework for my clion plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Added the intelliJ testFramework as new project library from Maven.
Name is `com.github.adedayo.intellij.sdk:testFramework:142.1` for anyone wondering.

In IntelliJ go to `Project Structure` -> `Libraries` -> Add a `New Project Library` -> `From Maven...`. Then search for `com.github.adedayo.intellij.sdk:testFramework:142.1` and simply add it.